# Theano error: NameError: global name 'CVM' is not defined

Tags: linux, machine-learning, theano, keras

All I'm trying to do is train my ANNs with keras and I get this absolutely nasty error from theano telling me `'CVM' is not defined`. I've tracked the error down to the `model.fit(input, output)` function my keras model.

I'm seen [mailing lists](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/theano-users/JoTu61_MTLk/G2ojrrXhEwAJ) which have directed me to `rm -rf ~/.theano` but this did not work.

I've reinstalled both theano and keras yet the error persists.

I tested training a simple keras network as the control (to eliminate the hypothesis my code causes the error), yet the error is present here as well.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
X = np.arange(10)
y = X*10
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.compile('sgd', 'mean_squared_error')

# Everything is OK up until here
# when I run 
model.fit(X,y)
```

Here's [a gist of my full error trace](https://gist.github.com/theideasmith/83dee968e22ccfc34e48642ef337b67a) and the tail of the error (from this snippet above):

```
<home>/.conda/envs/flytrackerML/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.pyc in make_vm(self, nodes, thunks, input_storage, output_storage, storage_map, post_thunk_clear, computed, compute_map, updated_vars)
    911 
    912             c0 = sys.getrefcount(node_n_inputs)
--> 913             vm = CVM(
    914                 nodes,
    915                 thunks,

NameError: global name 'CVM' is not defined
```

Comment: [this post](http://theano-users.narkive.com/kWW5ziT8/cvm-error-when-using-function) suggests that there is a conflict between a 32 bit and 64 bit installation. Did you check that?